# Error while Using TAPAS Pipeline for Table-Based Question Answering

Tags: python

I'm encountering an error while using the TAPAS pipeline for table-based question answering. Here's the code snippet I'm working with:

```py
from transformers import pipeline

# Load the TAPAS pipeline
nlp = pipeline(task="table-question-answering", model="google/tapas-large-finetuned-wtq")

# Sample tabular data
table = [
    ["Name", "Department", "Salary"],
    ["Alice", "HR", 50000],
    ["Bob", "Finance", 60000],
    ["Charlie", "IT", 75000],
]

# Sample natural language query
query = "What is the average salary in the IT department?"

# Perform table-based question answering
result = nlp(table=table, query=query)

# Extract the SQL query from the result
sql_query = result[0]['query']

# Print the generated SQL query
print("Generated SQL query:", sql_query)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-83edeea25bb6> in <cell line: 18>()
     16 
     17 # Perform table-based question answering
---> 18 result = nlp(table=table, query=query)
     19 
     20 # Extract the SQL query from the result

15 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    207     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
    208     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 209     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    210 
    211 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to resolve it. Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the full traceback, or at least point out which line the TypeError occurs at?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the documentation, I found a usage example. I have tested this code for your example and works fine but needs improvement:

```
from transformers import TapasTokenizer, TapasForQuestionAnswering
import pandas as pd

# Define the TAPAS model and tokenizer
model_name = "google/tapas-base-finetuned-wtq"
model = TapasForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = TapasTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Create a sample table as a DataFrame
data = {
    "Name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
    "Department": ["HR", "Finance", "IT"],
    "Salary": ["50000", "60000", "75000"]  # Convert salary to strings
}
table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# Define a list of natural language questions
queries = [
    "What is the name of the first employee?",
    "How much does Bob earn?",
    "What is the average salary in the IT department?"
]

# Tokenize the table and queries
inputs = tokenizer(table=table, queries=queries, padding="max_length", return_tensors="pt")

# Pass the tokenized inputs to the TAPAS model to obtain predictions
outputs = model(**inputs)
predicted_answer_coordinates, predicted_aggregation_indices = tokenizer.convert_logits_to_predictions(
    inputs, outputs.logits.detach(), outputs.logits_aggregation.detach()
)

# Map aggregation indices to human-readable aggregation types
id2aggregation = {0: "NONE", 1: "SUM", 2: "AVERAGE", 3: "COUNT"}
aggregation_predictions_string = [id2aggregation[x] for x in predicted_aggregation_indices]

# Extract and format the answers based on the predicted answer coordinates and aggregation types
answers = []
for coordinates in predicted_answer_coordinates:
    if len(coordinates) == 1:
        # Only a single cell:
        answers.append(table.iat[coordinates[0]])
    else:
        # Multiple cells
        cell_values = []
        for coordinate in coordinates:
            cell_values.append(str(table.iat[coordinate]))
        answers.append(", ".join(cell_values))

# Display the original table and print the questions along with their predicted answers and aggregation types
display(table)
print("")
for query, answer, predicted_agg in zip(queries, answers, aggregation_predictions_string):
    print(query)
    if predicted_agg == "NONE":
        print("Predicted answer: " + answer)
    else:
        print("Predicted answer: " + predicted_agg + " > " + answer)
```

#### Result

---

[image]

---

And to update your own code based on this info :

```
from transformers import pipeline

# Load the TAPAS pipeline
nlp = pipeline(task="table-question-answering", model="google/tapas-large-finetuned-wtq")

data = {
    "Name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
    "Department": ["HR", "Finance", "IT"],
    "Salary": ["50000", "60000", "75000"]  # Convert salary to strings
}
table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# Sample natural language query
query = "What is the average salary in the IT department?"

# Perform table-based question answering
result = nlp(table=table, query=query)

print(result)
```

### Result

```
{'answer': 'AVERAGE > 75000', 'coordinates': [(2, 2)], 'cells': ['75000'], 'aggregator': 'AVERAGE'}
```

---

To create SQL queries you can do something like this :

```
# Extract the aggregator and value
aggregator = result['aggregator']
value = result['cells'][0]
department = "IT"  # Replace with the actual department value from your question

# Construct the SQL query
sql_query = f"SELECT {aggregator}(Salary) FROM table WHERE Department = '{department}';"
print("Generated SQL query:", sql_query)
```

Comment: i have tired this code and now im getting another error


ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: I updated the code. Also I used Google Colab to test it and works just fine.

Comment: I'm truly so thankful for helping me. Sorry to bother you again but can u modify the above code so that i can get the sql query instead of the answer.

Comment: Glad to help. But TAPAS itself does not provide SQL queries. You need additional layers for creating queries based on model's answer. I updated code to give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you once again. I have tried defog.ai and openai and both are paid. Is there any other models that can help me get the queries from natural language

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, I believe there is none for free.